# upper and lower bounds for numeric variables in SAS

Tags: sas, limit

Maybe this is a noobish question, but I cannot find anywhere what is the lower and upper limit for a variable of numeric type in SAS. I found [this](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/dealing-with-numeric-representation-error-in-sas-applications.pdf) paper with all the theory behind it and on some forum a discussion saying that the upper limit is 1E200, but I am pretty sure it is (operating) system architecture dependent. Still, I would expect to have something more formal, like a constant MIN_NUMERIC_VALUE or MAX_NUMERIC_VALUE that I can use for comparison purposes to avoid overflows. Any relevant information is appreciated. 
Marius

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`CONSTANT`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002295680.htm) function gives you information like this.

```
%put %sysfunc(constant(big));
```

For a windows system, that is around 1.8e308.

As background, that number in Windows is based on storing numbers like so:

```
1 bit : sign
10 bits : exponent (the result is 2 to the power of this times the mantissa; 
                    this is like the 13 in 1.3425e13 in scientific notation)
53 bits : mantissa (this would be the 'decimal' portion, so the 1.3425 in the above.  
                    A fraction of 2, and strictly less than 2.)
```

The exponent can store as high as 2^10-1, so the actual number represented by just the exponent portion is 2^(2^10-1) times the mantissa.  The mantissa can be just less than 2, so highest number for any given exponent is 2^(exponent)*2 - 1.

Thus you can store 2^(2^10-1)*2-1, or 2^1024-1, which is almost 1.8e308.

Comment: Hey Joe! Thank you for your answer and level of details. I was already trying to make sense out of the doc, but I have not yet come so far with the calculations : ] much appreciated.

Comment: Nice. The CONSTANT function takes an argument "EXACTINT" that tells you the largest integer that can be stored in a variable. See this example: data _null_;do i=3 to 8;a=CONSTANT('EXACTINT',i);put i= a= 17.0;end;run;

Answer (score 0):

The largest integer you can store in a SAS variable on Windows is 9,007,199,254,740,992, using length=8.
[Here is a table of precission for different lengths on Windows](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#numvar.htm)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I found that table, same as in [here](http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug02/at/at002.pdf) on page 2. But that is more related to the limit of an integer to be accurately represented, not the boundaries of the legal numeric values. I figured out it is system dependent, but I am still expecting that the limits are set **and** stored in some constant.